# loading class with getResource() gives different results

Tags: java, classpath, classloader

I cannot understand how `Class.getResource()` and `ClassLoader.getResource()` methods works.
I wrote this:

```
public class Prova {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Prova.class.getResource("/java/lang/String.class"));
        System.out.println(String.class.getResource("/java/lang/String.class"));
        System.out.println(Prova.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/java/lang/String.class"));
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_301/lib/rt.jar!/java/lang/String.class
jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_301/lib/rt.jar!/java/lang/String.class
null
```

So, why is the third null? I would expect to get the same result as before.

Please notice that this is a simple case. Inside a webserver I have noticed much more weird situations; `null` appears in many more cases.

Comment: Why is this important to you? Why is this difference cruical?

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer I often use this snippet, at runtime, in order to understand where a particular class is loaded from (from a WAR, from EAR, from WAS module, ...) and it is important I don't get "null" as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class.getResource expects a path relative to its package subdirectory.
Absolute (=from the top directory) paths start with a `/`.

ClassLoader only knows absolute paths which are not allowed to start with a `/`.